# Hilbert Schmidt operators

Tags: hilbert-spaces, intuition, fa.functional-analysis

I don't know much about the theory of Hilbert spaces but a research project has me working with them a little bit.  In particular requiring an operator to be Hilbert-Schmidt is a recurring condition.

According to wikipedia one nice thing about H-S operators is that on a separable Hilbert space $H$ the set of H-S endomorphisms forms a Hilbert space that is naturally isomorphic to $H\otimes H^*$.

So I'm wondering what else is nice about H-S operators.  And what else works with H-S operators that wouldn't work for another class of operators.  Fredholm operators also come up a lot.  It $T$ is H-S and $S$ is Fredholm what can be said about the composition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the perfect reference for you is Lars Hörmander's *The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators*, vol III (the chapter on elliptic operators). There you'll find in perfect Hörmander style all you need about Fredholm, Hilbert-Schmidt, trace class operators. (As to the composition, H-S is a two-sided ideal; if S is any bounded operator TS and ST are H-S).

Comment: Oh Pietro, would it really hurt to type out "Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators"? =) Another good reference is Reed and Simon, "Methods of Mathematical Physics" vol 1 Chapter VI. 

Comment: sorry, fixed now

Comment: Generalized functions 4 of Gelfand and Shilov is good as well